# Regex match the words from a string without the start and end space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match some words from a string but with no success.

Let's say, for example, i have this string:

```
"word , word , two words, word"
```

What i'm trying to do is match the words, but without the space from start or end. But it should accept the spaces from in between the words. The array resulted from the match should be:

```
["word","word","two words","word"]
```

Could someone help or give me some insight on how would i go about doing this?

Thank you

Edit: what I've tried and succeed is doing it in two parts:

```
match(/[^(,)]+/g)
```

and using map to remove all the spaces from the resulting array:

```
map(value => value.trim());
```

But would like to do it only through regular expression and have no idea how to do it.

Comment: post your attempts

Comment: Try this `"word , word , two words, word".match(/(\w+\s*\w+)/g)`

Comment: @HassanImam This does not work with three words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\w[\w ]*?(?:(?=\s*,)|$)
```

Explanation:

```
\w[\w ]*?
```

Matches word characters with 0 or more spaces in between, but never at the start. (lazy)

```
(?:(?=\s*,)|$)
```

This non-capturing group looks ahead for spaces followed by `,`, *or* the end of string.

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/HqYhqS/1)

Answer (score 4):

You can just split on comma surrounded by optional spaces on either side:

```js
var str = "word , , word , two words, word";

var arr = str.split(/(?:\s*,\s*)+/);

console.log(arr);

//=> ["word", "word", "two words", "word"]
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer

Comment: When simple split option is available to you why chose a complex regex with lookahead and groups etc.

Comment: For example https://regex101.com/r/HqYhqS/2 takes only 58 steps to complete with `split` as against 216 steps with your selected regex.

Comment: @anubhava I think the "issue" is that, when splitting, empty items may find their way into the final result, try your regex with `"word , , word , two words, word"` string. With matching, you do not get empty elements in the result.

Comment: Then we can use `str.split(/(?:\s*,\s*)+/)` or see edited.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the following regex:

```
(\w+\s*\w+)
```

that matches

- 1 or more word character(s) followed by
- 0 to N white characters (whitespace character: space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab) followed by
- 1 or more word character(s).

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. I'll look over it

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're looking for with capture groups, so iterate over \1

```
\s*([\w\s]+)\s*
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer